# Get Country of IP Address with PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, ip-address, geoip, ip-geolocation

Ideally I'm trying to put together a PHP script that I can query from any web browser and it returns the country of the IP address that accessed the PHP script.

Is this possible or is there a better solution?

Comment: Obligatory note: IP-to-location is not a reliable method of source identification due to various proxies, VPNs and other horrors. According to the IP addresses, I am at this moment in Texas, Norway, Czech Republic, and Japan.

Comment: IPLocate.io provides a free API: [`https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8`](https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8) - Disclaimer: I run this service.

Comment: For a fast and reliable solution, you should try Ipregistry.co: https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout (disclaimer: I run the service).

Answer (score 88):

There are free, easy APIs you can use, like those:

- http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php
- http://www.ipgeo.com/api/
- http://ip2.cc/
- http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm
- https://iplocate.io/
- and plenty others.

Which one looks the most trustworthy is up to you :)

Otherwise, there are scripts which are based on local databases on your server. The database data needs to be updated regularly, though. Check out this one:

- http://phpweby.com/software/ip2country

HTH!

**Edit:**
And of course, depending on your project you might want to look at [HTML5 Location](http://html5demos.com/geo) features. You can't use them yet on the Internet Explorer (IE9 will support it, long way to go yet), but in case your audience is mainly on mobile devices or using Safari/Firefox it's definitely worth to look at it!

Once you have the coordinates, you can reverse geocode them to a country code. Again there are APIs like this one:

- Example: http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=47.03&lng=10.2
- More APIs: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html

**Update, April 2013**
Today I would recommend using [Geocoder](https://github.com/willdurand/Geocoder), a PHP library which makes it very easy to geocode ip addresses as well as postal address data.

***Update, September 2016
Since Google's privacy politics has changed, you can't use HTML5 Geolocation API if your server doesn't have HTPPS certificate or user doesn't allow you check his location. So now you can use user's IP and check in in PHP or get HTTPS certificate.

Comment: I think something changed on this api since the answer was posted, I'm now receiving the following error: "The GoogleMaps provider does not support IP addresses, only street addresses."

Comment: **[ipregistry.co](https://ipregistry.co)** is twice faster and accurate than ipdata.co: ipregistry.co/status (disclaimer: I run the service)

Answer (score 56):

There are various web APIs that will do this for you. Here's an example using my service, http://ipinfo.io:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
echo $details->country; // -> "US"
```

Web APIs are a nice quick and easy solution, but if you need to do a lot of lookups then having an IP -> country database on your own machine is a better solution. MaxMind offer a [free database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) that you can use with various PHP libraries, including [GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php).

Comment: I would refrain from implementing ipinfo.io in a production environment. I just pinned down major lag in our scripts, to a function that calls ipinfo.io for IP details. Make sure to test your provider choice thoroughly :)

Comment: That may have been true in the past, but they're now hosted across several providers and several cities for maximum availability and responsiveness - https://twitter.com/ipinfoio/status/458100167439159296

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. "193.238.152.59" recognized as FR, but it's UA.

Comment: I suggest trying out [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I run the service).

Comment: It is not safe to use in production with the free tier this days because it goes in rate limit.

Answer (score 27):

You can download ip-tables from MaxMind:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite

Import the CSV to your database (make sure to create an index for ip_long_from + ip_long_to). Then you can simply do:

```
$iplong = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

// should use mysqli with prepared statements etc, but just an example
mysql_query("
    SELECT country
    FROM ip_table
    WHERE $iplong BETWEEN ip_long_from AND ip_long_to
    LIMIT 1
");
```

Comment: This, it's an excellent way to get the country from an IP address.

Comment: i don't understand how do people get the localized city/country names, as geolite offers only a couple of languages

Comment: The most amazing thing is that adding indexes for "from" and "to" columns made the query take 10 times longer. Keeping the database unindexed worked best for me, together with LIMIT 1. Perhaps because the data is sorted in the CSV. Go figure.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example using http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip={$ip}"));
echo $details;
```

- See more at: http://channasmcs.blogspot.com/2014/11/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php.html#sthash.7u3WCwQq.dpuf

Answer (score 5):

Look at the GeoIP functions under "Other Basic Extensions."  http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Comment: They are not *really* built-in. http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.requirements.php

Comment: Correct it, then.

Answer (score 5):

I see there are a lot of answers, but no one of them mentions https://freegeoip.net/

You're allowed up to `15,000 queries per hour`. I think that's enough in most of the cases. Otherwise, you should think about using local databases from [MaxMind GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/).

**Freegeoip is open-source** and you can find sources on [github](https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip), deploy it locally and get rid of the query limits.

*Also, service provides **latitude/longitude/timezone** and other useful stuff.*

Answer (score 5):

```
$country_code = trim(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip_address}/country"))
```

will get you the country code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another free API for geolocation requests:
http://geoip.nekudo.com

Responses are in JSON format. Additionally the API sourcecode is available on github in case you need to setup your own API.

Answer (score 2):

Install and use [PHP's GeoIP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) if you can. On debian lenny:

```
sudo wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo mkdir -v /usr/share/GeoIP
sudo mv -v GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat

sudo apt-get install php5-geoip
# or sudo apt-get install php-geoip for PHP7
```

and then try it in PHP:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$country = geoip_country_name_by_name($ip);
echo 'The current user is located in: ' . $country;
```

returns:

```
The current user is located in: Cameroon
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post very helpful. It saved my day. 
http://www.techsirius.com/2014/05/simple-geo-tracking-system.html

Basically you need to install the IP database table and then do mysql query for the IP for location.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) OR die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) OR die(mysql_error());
$ip =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$long = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ip));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `geo_ips` WHERE '$long' BETWEEN `ip_start` AND `ip_end`";
$result = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
$ip_detail = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($ip_detail){
    echo $ip_detail['country']."', '".$ip_detail['state']."', '".$ip_detail['city'];
}
else{
    //Something wrong with IP
}
```

Comment: Well I can explain first, because it was my first or second post and number of words was not sufficient so one of moderator gave this post one negative point but I have no idea for second.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a good and updated database, for having more performance and not requesting external services from your website, [here](http://lite.ip2location.com/databases) there is a good place to download updated and accurate databases.

I'm recommending this because in my experience it was working excellent even including city and country location for my IP which most of other databases/apis failed to include/report my location except [this service](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) which directed me to this database.
 (My ip location was from "Rasht" City in "Iran" when I was testing and the ip was: `2.187.21.235` equal to `45815275`)

Therefore I recommend to use these services if you're unsure about which service is more accurate:

Database:
[`http://lite.ip2location.com/databases`](http://lite.ip2location.com/databases)

API Service:
[`http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php`](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the services of https://www.geoip-db.com They provide a JSON or JSONP-callback solution.

- JSON: https://geoip-db.com/json/
- JSONP: https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=callback

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents("https://www.geoip-db.com/json");
    $data = json_decode($json);

    print $data->country_code . "<br>";
    print $data->country_name . "<br>";
    print $data->state . "<br>";
    print $data->city . "<br>";
    print $data->postal . "<br>";
    print $data->latitude . "<br>";
    print $data->longitude . "<br>";
    print $data->IPv4 . "<br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://ip-api.io/ to get country name, city name, latitude and longitude. It supports IPv6.

As a bonus it will tell if ip address is a tor node, public proxy or spammer.

Php Code:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.io/json/64.30.228.118'));
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
{
"ip": "64.30.228.118",
"country_code": "US",
"country_name": "United States",
"region_code": "FL",
"region_name": "Florida",
"city": "Fort Lauderdale",
"zip_code": "33309",
"time_zone": "America/New_York",
"latitude": 26.1882,
"longitude": -80.1711,
"metro_code": 528,
"suspicious_factors": {
"is_proxy": false,
"is_tor_node": false,
"is_spam": false,
"is_suspicious": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run the service at [IPLocate.io](https://www.iplocate.io), which you can hook into for free with one easy call:

```
<?php
$res = file_get_contents('https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8');
$res = json_decode($res);

echo $res->country; // United States
echo $res->continent; // North America
echo $res->latitude; // 37.751
echo $res->longitude; // -97.822

var_dump($res);
```

The `$res` object will contain your geolocation fields like `country`, `city`, etc.

Check out the [docs](https://iplocate.docs.apiary.io) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

[Ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co) provides a scalable API to do this. With 10 global endpoints each able to handle >800M requests daily!

It also gives you the organisation, currency, timezone, calling code, flag and Tor Exit Node status data from any IPv4 or IPv6 address.

In php

```
php > $ip = '8.8.8.8';
php > $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/{$ip}"));
php > echo $details->region;
California
php > echo $details->city;
Mountain View
php > echo $details->country_name;
United States
php > echo $details->location;
37.405991,-122.078514
```

**Disclaimer**

I built this service.

Answer (score 0):

Use the widget [www.feedsalive.com](http://www.feedsalive.com), to get the country informations & last page information as well.