# Geolocate an IP without extensions?

Tags: php, geolocation, ip, php-extension, ip-geolocation

Is there a way to locate an IP's country without using any php extensions?

I know there are certain extensions, but is this possible without using extensions nor using other websites. For example:

```
www.[ip to country].[something]/?ip=123.123.123.123
```

Comment: some solutions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php

Answer (score 1):

Download a database that maps IP addresses to countries, e.g. [from MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite), and install it on the server.

There is no way to calculate the information stored in the database without accessing remote systems. That's why you really need a database for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$url = "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=173.194.41.103";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
printf("%s,%s", $json->geoplugin_regionName, $json->geoplugin_countryName);
```

Output

```
California,United States
```

Comment: The question asked if it is possible **without** using third-party services.