# How can I get the country name in a datagrid by providing ip address

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I would like to display the country name of visitor to admin page 
I have ip-address of visitor, how can I to use it to know the country name 
using an api?
or is there any other way? without the download of any new database for ipaddress
or use of jquery/js

Comment: Have you tried to find an answer before posting? Solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php

Comment: bt how to code it for asp:datagrid  and i have ipaddress table from this i want to know which i ipaddress is for which country

Answer (score 1):

There are some APIs for that. For example: [HostIP](http://www.hostip.info/use.html)