# how to get the server country like server time zone

Tags: php

I have used the `date_default_timezone_set()` to check and set the server time.

In the same way is this possible to get the server country in php?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Country of IP Address with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the host.info api](http://www.host.info), combined with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`... easy.

This question is a dupe, though, and the duplicate question (auto-commented) contains some more alternative API's you can use

Answer (score 1):

There's no such function in PHP, but you can get the country from remote IP with a little help of some database [like this](http://www.hostip.info/use.html).