# I am making custom shipping method in woocomerce. I want to allow only USA

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I am making a custom shipping method in woocommerce. I want to deliver my goods only in USA. I want to allow my shipping method to US resident only. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a IP geolocation service like the one mentioned here:
[stackoverflow link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php) or here: [stackoverflow link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address)
You can find a code snippet in the links. Basically you use PHP or jQuery to call an API and get the user's location from his IP, then change the page accordingly.

Comment: When user select country after selecting my shipping method, he can only see my allowed countries (i.e Only US, I can add more countries on back end, if I want to)