# How to make a post visible only to 1 or 2 countries

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have no idea, how to make a post visible only to one or 2 countries. How will the code gets to know, from which country the user is? Give me some hints and tips. 
It should be without making any account.

Comment: I have seen this somewhere before, is this the current homework project

Comment: here is a scenario user enters the website we check with his ip address if he from x country you allow him to view the post if he from y country you don't allow him

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Country of IP Address with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of server variables like $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] etc by which you can find the logged in user's IP address.

Check out: [PHP Server variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Once you retrieve those, there are quite a few API's which could be used to determine the user's country.

You can use these as references:

1. [Getting visitors country from their IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip)
2. [Get Country of IP Address with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine their country from their ip.  Check this site out: http://ipinfo.io/.

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    if (response.country == 'whatever country') {
        // show whatever content
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: Not sure if writing client side code for such things are a good idea. It's better to keep your business logic on the server side.

Comment: In this case it's probably fine, if somebody's going to be doing malicious things to hide their IP address server-side validation doesn't beat a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Apply the IP out of Server into an API.  The manual describes one such set of functions.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 0):

there are several options

1. build your own IP to country database and application to detect country
2. use API service like http://ipinfo.io, http://ip-api.com/docs/ etc...
3. host with cloudflare and use `$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];` https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-CloudFlare-IP-Geolocation-do-