# Get the country name from CSV file for all IP addresses

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get all country names from IP addresses. I have a CSV file in which all IP addresses are described and I want to get all country names at once. Any have an idea how to do it?

I am using the code below, but it works only for single values. How can I do this for multiple IP addresses?

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="ip" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
</form>

<?php

function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr) {
    $url="http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=5cfaab6c5af420b7b0f88d289571b990763e37b66761b2f053246f9db07ca913&ip=$ipAddr&format=json%22";
    $d = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($d , true);
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $ip=countryCityFromIP($_REQUEST['ip']);
    print_r($ip);
    echo $ip['countryName'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php

Comment: Its use only for single IP address I want to get to multiple IP address

Comment: Could you post a code snippet? Also what have you tried?

Comment: <form method="post">
<input type="text" name="ip" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
<?php
function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr)
{
    $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=5cfaab6c5af420b7b0f88d289571b990763e37b66761b2f053246f9db07ca913&ip=$ipAddr&format=json";
    $d = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($d , true);
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
   $ip=countryCityFromIP($_REQUEST['ip']);

   print_r($ip);
   echo $ip['countryName'];
}
?>

Comment: Am using this but its work only for single value . I have no any idea how i can do for multiples ip address

Comment: It's too late already, but I suggest *not* including your API key in the question. That's almost as bad as providing your password. You may want to go find out if you can change the key now that it's public knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code

The input should be comma-separated list of IP addresses

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="ip" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
</form>

<?php

function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr) {
    $url="http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=5cfaab6c5af420b7b0f88d289571b990763e37b66761b2f053246f9db07ca913&ip=$ipAddr&format=json%22";
    $d = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($d , true);
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    foreach(explode(',', $_REQUEST['ip']) as $ip) {
        $ip = countryCityFromIP($ip[);
        print_r($ip);
        echo $ip['countryName'];
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: looking this code $url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=2b3d7d0ad1a285279139487ce77f3f58d980eea9546b5ccc5d08f5ee62ce7471&ip=".'124.40.244.19'."&format=json"));
echo $url->countryName;

Comment: in this code i want to enter multiple ip addresses so please tell me how can i do it.