# Currency conversion based on location and Paypal payments

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In a Prestashop 1.6 based store I want to accept payments via Paypal in only one currency (Euros). However, I want to show prices in other currencies based on the location of the customer (probably using it's IP address?). How can I do that?

Comment: What I know is how to show prices in other currencies based on the location of the customer using his/her IP. But I don't know how to implement the functionality to accept payments via Paypal in only one currency. If interested please contact.

Comment: Can you please explain how you do the first part @Nimish?

Answer (score 0):

In Modules and services > payment you have a tab CURRENCY RESTRICTIONS, you can check in which currency you would like Paypal to be available

For currecy selection by IP:
First, you should get the user IP after, you should set the curency of the Prestashop context

```
$this->context->currency->id = $id_currency
```

To get $id_currency, follow this steps

- You should get the country of the the user IP with this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php)
- Then get the currency code by country code (you can get if from a csv file or you you should use an API or database)

Comment: Regarding currency restrictions, I want PayPal to be available to all users but even when the price is presented in another currency to the user on the procust page I want the payment to be processed in Euros through PayPal.
Regarding the geolocation, I think Prestashop already has support for this. Am I worng?

Comment: @notGeek for Paypal you should change unto the module code, "but even when the price is presented in another currency to the user" what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is: the price need to be shown in customer currency but when he pays, I want the payment to be processed always in Euros.

Comment: @notGeek I think you should create a new override for PaymentModuleClass and override the validateOrder method and you have just to change id_currency there on line 181
Change $id_currency = $currency_special ? (int)$currency_special : (int)$this->context->cart->id_currency; to $id_currency = '$id_euro_currency';

Answer (score -1):

The free [IP Find](https://ipfind.co) service provides currency information in the response for any given IP Address.

Eg. `http://ipfind.co?ip=8.8.8.8`

Will return (among other things)

`currency: USD`