# Azure website on a VM: how to allow access only to IP addresses in India

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have a website on Centos Azure VM. Is there a way to allow access, only to IP Addresses in India
Rather than controlling the IPs from application can we restrict it from server end or from Portal like using NSG's or something

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a geolocation service to get the country from the user IP address.  Check this answer for more info: [Get Country of IP Address with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php)